Why does the community bot only have 1 reputation?
I recently edited my post from an unlogged browser, and the edit goes to the community bot, as its profile also says:

I do things like

...
Own suggested edits from anonymous users


So why can't it gain reputation for editing posts (when accepted)?

Why so many downvotes? I know userAporva Shukla can't respond but the downvotes seem excessive for what is a legitimate question albeit a duplicate.

Looking at the edit history it seems there was a bit of a war of the edits. OK, this behaviour often attracts DV because it is disruptive and disrespectul to the user who did care enough to post an answer. Still 16 downvotes suggests the post is very low-quality, which it isn't.

@Mari-Lou downvotes here mean people don't agree with the request or idea. In this case it's not because it's a duplicate, but because it suggests a new feature: "gain reputation for editing posts", for the Community bot. People just disagree with this. Simple as that, nothing personal, nothing is "not nice".

@ShadowWizard 'it suggests a new feature: "gain reputation for editing posts", for the Community bot.' Huh? Since the very first revision, the question just asked why the bot does not gain reputation for editing. At least from what is left, there is no indication that it ever requested/suggested that the bot should gain the reputation.

"Shukla deleted the question but then a moderator undeleted it" - that's not what happened at all. A moderator deleted and undeleted the question, presumably to cancel the delete vote it had accumulated and prevent the question from being deleted. You can see that very clearly in the timeline.

@F1Krazy To be clear, the undelete and redelete was an accident. Modding on mobile is really hard. The buttons are tiny :-(

Respectfully, folks, digging into this user's suspension and opining on the other issues at play here isn't great for anyone, and it could really have an effect on Apoorva here. I've deleted a boatload of comments related to that. Let's keep this focused on this specific question and its content.

Reputation is "a rough measurement of how much the community trusts" a user, but the actions (not just edits) of a lot of different people are attributed to "Community", so there wouldn't be much use to such a statistic. Keeping its reputation at 1 is simple and a good reminder that it's not a person.
If you want to audit anonymous suggested edits, use the suggested edit stats tool (requires "access to moderator tools", typically awarded at 10k) or SEDE.
